# Optimize many Intervals in Joda Time

Tags: java, algorithm, jodatime

I have a bunch of Joda time [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) objects stored in a List. All of these Intervals have valid start and end instants. These Intervals can have any overlaps, abuts or even gaps among themselves.

I want to flatten (optimize) these Intervals to the maximum possible. I mean, I have to generate other Interval objets that will represent the very same from - to information, but without redundancy.

For example:

I1: 2012-01-12T05:00:00.000/2013-03-18T14:00:00.000

I2: 2012-04-12T04:00:00.000/2013-02-10T06:00:00.000

I3: 2015-12-12T04:00:00.000/2016-12-12T06:00:00.000

Should produce:

I1_o: 2012-01-12T05:00:00.000/2013-03-18T14:00:00.000

I2_o: 2015-12-12T04:00:00.000/2016-12-12T06:00:00.000

(I2 is absolutely within I1, so can be ignored, and the resulted two has a gap).

I know the three methods in Interval class that can help me, but I guess I need a more generic algorithm that can search overlaps between some kind of intervals, like ordinary numbers, etc.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the intervals by start time and loop through the intervals. If the start time of interval *i* is less than or equal to the end time of interval *i-1*, they can be merged into one interval whose end time is the greatest end time of the two original intervals. (Put the resulting intervals into a new list so that you can safely loop through the sorted list of original intervals without modifying it.)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great core step! A little fix: you have to examine the start time of i and i-1, and use the earlier as the result's start time. Also, the resulted Intervals may have to be "reoptimized", so the core step you mentioned may have to be executed on the result, too. And last, this step should handle standalone intervals, that are not sharing any time with other intervals. Anyways, your answer gave me the idea, thanks!

Comment: @gyabraham: True; I could have been more precise (but apparently, you got the idea) - you always keep track of the current interval you're building up, and you always compare interval _i_ to the current interval, and either merge the intervals, or set _i_ to be the new current interval.

Comment: @gyabraham Sorting the intervals by start time means that "a little fix" is unnecessary; the interval that sorted earlier has the earlier start time.

Answer (score 1):

Scala pattern:

```
intervals.sortWith(_.start isAfter _.start).foldLeft(Seq[Interval]()) {
  case (Nil, e) => Seq(e)
  case (h :: t, e) if ((h gap e) == null) =>
    new Interval(e.interval.start, h.interval.end) +: t
  case (a, e) => e +: a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More generic algorithm explained http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

Answer (score 0):

```
seq.sortWith(_.getStart isAfter _.getStart).foldLeft(Seq[Interval]()) {
  case (Nil, e) => Seq(e)
  case (h :: t, e) if (h gap e) == null =>
    val ins = if (h.contains(e)) {
      h
    } else if (e.contains(h)) {
      e
    } else {
      new Interval(e.getStart, h.getEnd)
    }
    ins +: t
  case (a, e) => e +: a
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.